# SIGSEGV error when trying to use AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

**NOTE: This error is only reproducible on Tablet devices, I do not get anything improper on mobile devices.**

I am trying to set up an AutoCompleteText view in one of my projects, the idea is based on [this](http://garbtech.co.uk/android-implementing-a-google-maps-search-box-with-autocompletetextview-and-geocoder-api/)

The IDE warned me about:

```
 private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            DelayAutoCompleteTextView.super.performFiltering((CharSequence) msg.obj, msg.arg1);
        }
    };
```

to be static or leaks might occur, I have changed it into the following:

```
 Handler mIncomingHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

            DelayAutoCompleteTextView.super.performFiltering((CharSequence) msg.obj, msg.arg1);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

I am not sure if the error is being raised due to the above.

I use this function to get search results:

```
 public List<AutoCompleteResultItem> runInBackgroundThread(String searchQuery) {
        final List<AutoCompleteResultItem> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("mode", "add");
            jsonObject.put("term", searchQuery);

            String js = " https://***.***.com/mobile/company/suggest_company_name";
            System.out.println("temp: " + js);

            String firstResponse = UniversalHttpUrlConnection.postJSONObject(js, jsonObject);
            System.out.println("Response: " + firstResponse);


            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(firstResponse);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject r = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                list.add(new AutoCompleteResultItem(r.getString("text")));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

instead of the `findLocations` method in original post with link above. Where do I go from here?

Error Log:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 2945 (Filter)
12-01 18:11:24.377 83-83/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-01 18:11:24.377 83-83/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'softwinners/nuclear_mid/nuclear-mid:4.2.2/JDQ39/20131218:eng/test-keys'
12-01 18:11:24.377 83-83/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '41275'
12-01 18:11:24.377 83-83/? I/DEBUG: pid: 2296, tid: 2945, name: Filter  >>> projects.test.com.webviewtest <<<
12-01 18:11:24.377 83-83/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
12-01 18:11:24.967 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 deadd00d  r3 00000000
12-01 18:11:24.967 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     r4 408a41b0  r5 0000020c  r6 413d3a80  r7 408410f1
12-01 18:11:24.967 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     r8 413d3a80  r9 40171228  sl 4c48ac78  fp 4ddf5c8c
12-01 18:11:24.967 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     ip 00004000  sp 4ddf58d8  lr 401430d9  pc 4083bbc0  cpsr 60000030
12-01 18:11:24.967 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d0  74726f6261204d56  d1  2e6874726570616e
12-01 18:11:24.967 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d2  ffffffffffffff75  d3  ffffffffffffff6c
12-01 18:11:24.967 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d4  ffffffffffffffff  d5  ffffffffffffffff
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d6  ffffffffffffffff  d7  ffffffffffffffff
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d16 0000000000000013  d17 0000000000000013
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d18 0000000000000000  d19 3ff0000000000000
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d24 0000000000000001  d25 0000000000000000
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000036
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d28 0000000000000023  d29 0000000000000001
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 0000000000000001
12-01 18:11:24.977 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     scr 20000093
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #00  pc 00045bc0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+75)
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #01  pc 0004a0d7  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+210)
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #02  pc 0004af79  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #03  pc 0023dd5d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #04  pc 00233211  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #05  pc 002332ed  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #06  pc 00238e4d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #07  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #08  pc 0004d1d9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+392)
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #09  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #10  pc 0002b54c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
12-01 18:11:24.997 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #11  pc 0005f9c9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #12  pc 0005f9f3  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #13  pc 0005456f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #14  pc 0000e3b8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #15  pc 0000dab0  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5898  00000001  
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf589c  4016e1b4  /system/lib/libc.so
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58a0  4016e1b4  /system/lib/libc.so
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58a4  4016e1b4  /system/lib/libc.so
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58a8  4016e1b4  /system/lib/libc.so
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58ac  401430d9  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush_locked+36)
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58b0  4016e254  /system/lib/libc.so
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58b4  4016e1b4  /system/lib/libc.so
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58b8  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.007 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58bc  401440a9  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+32)
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58c0  408a41b0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58c4  0000020c  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58c8  413d3a80  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58cc  408410f1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58d0  df0027ad  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58d4  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #00  4ddf58d8  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58dc  6c756e28  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58e0  0000296c  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58e4  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58e8  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58ec  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58f0  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58f4  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58f8  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf58fc  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5900  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5904  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5908  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf590c  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5910  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5914  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          ........  ........
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #01  4ddf5af0  413d3a80  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5af4  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5af8  40840f5d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5afc  40840f7d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     #02  4ddf5b00  4c48bb40  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5b04  4c48ac68  
12-01 18:11:25.017 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5b08  00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5b0c  4ddf5b5c  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5b10  4c48bb40  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:          4ddf5b14  4b062d5f  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4190 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a41a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a41b0 40f60990 40f60980 00400000 03000000  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a41c0 03000000 00000000 00000000 3fe00000  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a41d0 00080000 00200000 00004000 00006000  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a41e0 00000001 00000101 00000002 00000001  
12-01 18:11:25.027 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a41f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4200 00000000 4025d7f5 4025e221 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4210 4025d7e1 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4220 40f60b70 00000000 00000002 00000003  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4230 00000001 00000001 00000000 00000100  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4240 00000000 40f60af0 00000003 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4250 40f60ae0 40052e30 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4260 40f60f98 50000c38 40004008 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4270 40bfceb8 40bfced8 40f611e8 40f612a8  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408a4280 40f61350 40f613f8 40f614a0 40f61548  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3a60 40f620e0 00000000 413d39f8 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3a70 00000000 0000001b 00000000 00000023  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3a80 40f63c58 00000000 413d3a80 413d3aa0  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3a90 413d3b80 00000000 40f6f070 00000023  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3aa0 40f620e0 00000000 413d3ac0 48c14184  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3ab0 00000000 00000054 00000000 000000c3  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3ac0 40f62950 00000000 00000054 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.037 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3ad0 00610043 006c006c 00430020 006f006f  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3ae0 0069006b 00530065 006e0079 004d0063  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3af0 006e0061 00670061 00720065 003a003a  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b00 00720063 00610065 00650074 006e0049  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b10 00740073 006e0061 00650063 00290028  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b20 006f0020 00200072 00720063 00610065  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b30 00650074 00610020 00770020 00620065  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b40 00690076 00770065 00620020 00660065  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b50 0072006f 00200065 00730075 006e0069  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408410d0 bdf0b005 46294630 f01f463a 4604fec7  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408410e0 d1f12800 bf00e7e3 0005ea40 00047610  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408410f0 41ffe92d 460c4607 4639a803 4615461e  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841100 ffaef7fd 98034621 ff7cf7fe 46046ac3  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841110 d0322b07 fa3cf01f b3384680 f8d8e02d  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841120 07020004 f108d422 f0390014 f8d8f8fd  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841130 49163010 44794a16 4607447a e88d2003  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841140 69a30088 ebb6f7d2 f7d24638 4b11eba2  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841150 0800f04f 447b69a2 490f681b 44799200  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841160 01ecf8d3 4633462a f832f7f9 f7fda803  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841170 4640ff9b e8bdb004 462081f0 46324629  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841180 ff46f01f 28004680 e7e0d1c9 00042ae4  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40841190 000475ce 0005e99e 000475e3 b5f74684  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408411a0 a801460e 46174661 4508e9dd ff58f7fd  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408411b0 46319801 ff26f7fe f01368fb 693b0f40  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     408411c0 18c2d005 46204629 ec82f7dc 18c0e002  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3a60 40f620e0 00000000 413d39f8 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.047 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3a70 00000000 0000001b 00000000 00000023  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3a80 40f63c58 00000000 413d3a80 413d3aa0  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3a90 413d3b80 00000000 40f6f070 00000023  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3aa0 40f620e0 00000000 413d3ac0 48c14184  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3ab0 00000000 00000054 00000000 000000c3  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3ac0 40f62950 00000000 00000054 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3ad0 00610043 006c006c 00430020 006f006f  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3ae0 0069006b 00530065 006e0079 004d0063  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3af0 006e0061 00670061 00720065 003a003a  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b00 00720063 00610065 00650074 006e0049  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b10 00740073 006e0061 00650063 00290028  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b20 006f0020 00200072 00720063 00610065  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b30 00650074 00610020 00770020 00620065  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b40 00690076 00770065 00620020 00660065  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     413d3b50 0072006f 00200065 00730075 006e0069  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171208 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171218 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171228 f05e470c 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171238 00000007 00000002 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171248 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171258 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171268 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171278 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171288 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40171298 00000000 00000000 002f4831 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401712a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401712b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401712c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401712d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.057 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401712e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.067 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401712f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000  
12-01 18:11:25.067 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ac58 00000000 00000000 00000028 00000453  
12-01 18:11:25.067 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ac68 45ffa570 480c3e00 4513bb78 471db000  
12-01 18:11:25.067 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ac78 413d3a60 48121700 4ddf5da0 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.067 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ac88 4ddf5dd4 00000010 00000000 40814400  
12-01 18:11:25.067 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ac98 00000000 00000000 404bf470 480c0300  
12-01 18:11:25.067 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48aca8 00000000 413d3a80 00000001 00004000  
12-01 18:11:25.067 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48acb8 00000000 4c47d060 40814400 408192c0  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48acc8 00000000 4081d3bc 4081d430 4081d2e0  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48acd8 4081d300 4081d35c 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ace8 472d3008 00000028 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48acf8 00000000 00000000 00002000 408a48d4  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ad08 40f620e0 44f65830 00000003 4c48b570  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ad18 00000001 00000040 00000200 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ad28 00000003 460dafdc 460dafdc 00000006  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ad38 460db040 45010f78 00000000 13e15b0b  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4c48ad48 00000000 00000000 14043de4 13e8dc68  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5c6c 00000004 480c3e08 40814294 480c3e00  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5c7c 00000001 4112ad50 46d2cc4c 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5c8c 408431dd 480c3e00 46d2cc49 4b05de15  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5c9c 4c48ac78 1e100001 00000000 00000016  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5cac 40171228 413d3990 413d3990 4c48afd4  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5cbc 413d3990 00000003 4c48ac68 00000016  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5ccc 413d3990 00000000 4084abbd 413d3990  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5cdc 00000000 408a41b0 00000016 4ddf5d54  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5cec 4513b83c 00000001 4112ad50 00000001  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5cfc 4513b828 000001f8 46e4ec0f 00000008  
12-01 18:11:25.077 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5d0c 00000001 4ddf5d54 40860ba5 46e4ec0f  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5d1c 4112ad50 46e4ec0f 0000a563 471db000  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5d2c 00000002 4687eea8 40171228 40008ca0  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5d3c 4086103f 4ddf5d54 46e4ec0f 4ddf5d54  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5d4c 408616a1 413d3a60 40008ca0 0000139e  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5d5c 45ffa5b4 00000018 4c48ac68 408a41b0  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00003fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00003ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     00004090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     000040a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     000040b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.087 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     000040c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     000040d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf58b8 00000000 401440a9 408a41b0 0000020c  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf58c8 413d3a80 408410f1 df0027ad 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf58d8 00000000 6c756e28 0000296c 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf58e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf58f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5908 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5918 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5928 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5938 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5948 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5958 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5968 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5978 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5988 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf5998 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.097 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4ddf59a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-01 18:11:25.107 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bba0 34ccf8d3 efd0f7d7 461d2300 b1525d1a  
12-01 18:11:25.107 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bbb0 18ad3301 7f00f5b3 e004d1f8 4a0a4798  
12-01 18:11:25.107 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bbc0 f7d77015 490cefc8 4a0c2006 44794c0c  
12-01 18:11:25.107 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bbd0 447c447a ee6ef7d7 f7d72000 6de3ef14  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bbe0 d1eb2b00 bf00e7eb deadd00d 00063f8c  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bbf0 00068614 00048c75 0004804c 00049ed1  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc00 000685da 4605b530 b08b4c15 a8034915  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc10 6824447c 4479462a 93096823 f8e1f009  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc20 2100aa0a f8429808 f0091d20 b958fd05  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc30 462b9802 4a0d490c 90004479 2006447a  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc40 ee38f7d7 ff96f7ff f7f2a803 9a09ff61  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc50 428a6821 f7d7d001 b00beeb2 bf00bd30  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc60 00063ef8 00049e97 00047fe2 00049e7a  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc70 1a55b5f8 1c69460e 46174604 ecc0f7e5  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc80 696042b7 4631d004 f7d7462a 1940ee1a  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     4083bc90 23006120 bdf87003 4604b538 460d6120  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401430b8 447e4e08 68336836 f000b10b 4620fa4c  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401430c8 ffcaf7ff 68304605 4620b110 fa50f000  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401430d8 bd704628 0002ae82 4604b570 4811b928  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401430e8 e8bd4478 f0004070 4e0fbfcb 6836447e  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401430f8 b10b6833 fa2ff000 f01089a0 d1060f18  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143108 fedaf7f1 35fff04f 60012109 4620e003  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143118 ffa2f7ff 68324605 4620b112 fa28f000  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143128 bd704628 ffffffc9 0002ae48 44794909  
12-01 18:11:25.117 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143138 680b6809 6843b963 60421e5a da012a00  
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143148 bba0f001 f8116801 6001cb01 47704660  
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143158 bff4f000 0002ae06 47f0e92d 4f3e4604  
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143168 447f4688 683b683f f000b10b 6860f9f4  
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143178 dc042800 f0014620 2800fad5 6826d15f  
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143188 6865210a 462a4630 fe31f007 3001b168  
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     40143198 c00cf8b4 f8c81b81 68621000 5300f44c  
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     401431a8 1a5381a3 0009e884 4606e043 f1056ca0  
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     beb9d000-bebbe000 [stack]
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     (no map for address)
12-01 18:11:25.127 83-83/? I/DEBUG:     ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
12-01 18:11:25.337 192-192/? D/Zygote: Process 2296 terminated by signal (11)
```

These are my class files:

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    private static int MAX_RESULTS;
    private static int THRESHOLD;
    private List resultList = new ArrayList();


    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AutoCompleteResultItem getItem(int position) {
        return (AutoCompleteResultItem) resultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.geo_search_result, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.geo_search_result_text)).setText(getItem(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {

                    List names = runInBackgroundThread(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = names;
                    filterResults.count = names.size();
                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count != 0) {
                    resultList = (List) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };


        return filter;
    }
```

}
    public class AutoCompleteResultItem {

```
    String name;
    public AutoCompleteResultItem(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: At which point exactly does the app crash? Put a few breakpoints in your methods and try to narrow down to the exact line where the app crashes. Also put any other error you can find, this one is not very useful.

Comment: what do you need mIncomingHandler for?  why do you use a custom adapter with a custom Filter?

Comment: The app does not CRASH, I do not get any Errors on the log trace. The error happens in an activity, once I type 3 characters (Which is also the threshold for the Autocomplete view) I am returned to the launching activity - No ANR - No Unfortunately stopped and No Error logs.

Comment: Only when I turned off the filter in my log cat I got the above details about SIGSGEV error.

Comment: @pskink There are certain criteria, based upon which I chose to use the model I have implemented: Suggestions data fetching must be performed in a separate thread
Data fetching should start only when a user pauses typing (to prevent a bunch of requests to a server after every entered character)
Suggestions should be shown only if the user enters a string of some minimum length (no reason to start data fetching for string of 2 or 3 characters)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830 change the threshold and of course web api stuff (i used threshold == 1 and wikipedia web api)

Comment: I am beginning to believe that, this error occurs for me on each network request I make in the app. Just checked it. However it works fine when done from a mobile phone. Mind melting kind of. I will have a look there @pskink